# I'm a noob, plz help me quick!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I'm a programmer and I have a deadline to finish a difficult project, I need your help **now**.

I would ask it on Stackoverflow, but it's probably gonna get closed, so I'm reaching out on this SE.

`[![edit image description here][1]][1]`

---

May come in handy:

> <sub>19-5-1-21 4-5 16-5-9-14-20-21-18-5</sub>

Comment: Lol, I very nearly voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: You are ***definitely*** a noob, it must be `enter image description here`, not `edit`!

Comment: @nicael nice to meet you too, it was done so intentionally.

Comment: (it wasn't an insult rather than a joke based on the question title, but I see your point now :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

So, you want me to...

> gimme moar of teh codez?

I vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". ;)

The solution:

> Editing the question shows the image that is incorrectly linked is at `https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf15u.png`, which contains:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Doing a ROT13 on this gives a new image link `https://i.stack.imgur.com/icgB6.png`, which contains:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Replacing the file name gives the new link `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cli7O.png`, which contains:
>
>  [image]
>
>  And you can sorta see a ghostly image in the white. Adjusting the contrast (I actually just did `imshow(all(imread('Cli7O.png') == 255, 3))` in MATLAB), we get:
>
>  [image]
>
>  And another ROT13 of this gives `gimme moar of teh codez`.

Comment: that was quicker then I thought :D, awaiting explanation before I accept.

Comment: If only you wrote the explanation before posting the answer... 
Ah well, it was a fun treasure hunt.

Comment: @WELZ since you're asking on this site, it looks like your project is screwed

Comment: steganography that was :D. facepalms

Comment: I just tilted my screen.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: That's not how ROT13 works. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Ok solved by gnovice, but I am guessing the hint is

> seau de peinture - paint bucket in french... which made me start searching through the images of the post n- simple substitution 1-a, 2-b, etc. .... this was for the white image to reveal the message....

Comment: Yep, what @gnovice mentioned for the final part could've been done with this as well (for those who don't have "that" tool he used)