# Why did they close my riddle?

Tags: riddle, cipher, humor

So I came up with this -at least what I thought to be a- great riddle and posted it on this site.

Within minutes, it was closed by the community. It said:

*This looks like a puzzle you found somewhere. For the content you did not create proper attribution is required*.....  and so on.

It upset me. I am scrambling to find out why. Here was my riddle: A simple cipher.

[image: In fancy yellow font, "Yea", then "undo shift", then "1/10" (or the fraction one-tenths)]

Comment: Please don't let this get into the HNQ table. Maybe ask the typography people about the spacing—I'll even give you an em dash or two to pass on—but *please* don't give the gimme-teh-codez an excuse?

Comment: Of course it hit HNQ

Comment: The Stack Exchange version of click bait!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To solve this puzzle, note the key word in the text:

> *scrambling* - this is a nod towards using **anagrams**.

If we employ this on each of the three parts of the puzzle text, we can get the following:

> YEA → **AYE** (a homophone for 'I')
>
>  UNDO SHIFT → **FOUND THIS**
>
>  1/10 = ONE TENTH → **ON THE NET**

So the reason your puzzle was closed is because it seems like you were telling us:

> **I FOUND THIS ON THE NET**!

So please provide suitable attribution!! ;-)

Comment: Perfectly done once again @Stiv. You even picked up on Scrambling.

Comment: I really thought this was more suited for meta, before I realised it was an actual puzzle. ;) Creative! +1 for you

Comment: @riskymysteries Here's [another awsome similar-looking puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63261/53154) in case you haven't seen it before (check the first comment there too).